# Adobe Premiere Pro CC 2015 Support with NVIDIA GeForce 820M

Tags: graphics-card, gpu, adobe-premiere

I was just checking the Adobe Premiere Pro website for hardware requirement for better performance and I saw that they recommend using below GPUs.

Windows CUDA:

```
NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M
NVIDIA GeForce GT 750M
NVIDIA GeForce GT 755M
NVIDIA GeForce GTX 675MX
NVIDIA GeForce GTX 680
NVIDIA GeForce GTX 680MX
NVIDIA GeForce GTX 690
NVIDIA GeForce GTX 770
NVIDIA GeForce GTX 775M
NVIDIA GeForce GTX 780
NVIDIA GeForce GTX 780M
NVIDIA GeForce GTX TITAN
NVIDIA Quadro K1100M
NVIDIA Quadro K2000
NVIDIA Quadro K2100M
NVIDIA Quadro K2200
NVIDIA Quadro K2000M
NVIDIA Quadro K3000M
NVIDIA Quadro K4000
NVIDIA Quadro K4000M
NVIDIA Quadro K4100M
NVIDIA Quadro K4200
NVIDIA Quadro K5000
NVIDIA Quadro K5000M
NVIDIA Quadro K5200
NVIDIA Quadro K6000
NVIDIA Quadro M2000
NVIDIA Quadro M4000
NVIDIA Quadro M5000
NVIDIA Quadro M5500
NVIDIA Quadro M6000
NVIDIA Tesla K10
```

My machine specs are:

```
Intel Core i5 4210U @ 1.70GHz
8.00GB Single-Channel DDR3 @ 798MHz
Intel HD Graphics Family (Dell) 997 MHz
NVIDIA GeForce 820M
```

and my questions are:

1. Can and Should I use my NVIDIA GeForce 820M GPU with Adobe Premiere Pro CC 2015?
2. Or should I go for replacing my 820M with some other GPU from the list?
   Note: My usage is making YouTube videos like cover songs and all.
3. There is a small observation though, when I use built-in Intel HD Graphic Card, the cursor movement in the video project is way smoother than when selected NVIDIA graphic card. Why is that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use  your Nvidia GPU , pertaining to cursor movements try tweaking your gpu settings for quality enhancement,  for that open the Nvidia control panel and change anisotropic filtering, etc another important thing is to check if you hardware acceleration enabled rather than software. Some gpu work better with hardware acceleration, also check phys X processor in use.

Comment: Sure Anytime! :)

Answer (score 0):

Of course. You could do it. If I'm not wrong, you already have higher GPU then, required spec. Though, the RAM speed is a bit slower to operate multimedia project as expected, if u gonna make high end video like 4K resolution.

Comment: There is a small observation though, when I use built-in Intel HD Graphic Card, the cursor movement in the video project is way smoother than when selected NVIDIA graphic card. Why is that?